# subtraction not working in java program (missing something)

Tags: java, subtraction

I put together this program, my first one ever but after I enter the values in the boxes, the output in the end is "0" and not the subtraction. I don't know what i am missing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class PSEUDOCODE_PROGRAM {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner scnr= new Scanner(System.in);

   String applesHad = " ";
   String applesNeed = " ";
   String orangesHad = " ";
   String orangesNeed = " ";
   int applesTheyHave = 0;
   int applesTheyNeed = 0;
   int orangesTheyHave = 0;
   int orangesTheyNeed = 0;
   int applesToOrder = 0;
   int orangesToOrder = 0;
   applesToOrder = applesTheyNeed - applesTheyHave;
   orangesToOrder = orangesTheyNeed - orangesTheyHave;

//Ask produce buyer how many apples are in stock
applesHad= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many apples do you have: ");
applesTheyHave = Integer.parseInt(applesHad);
applesHad= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many apples do you need: ");
applesTheyNeed = Integer.parseInt(applesHad);
//Ask produce buyer how many oranges are in stock
orangesHad= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many oranges do you have:      ");
orangesTheyHave = Integer.parseInt(orangesHad);
orangesHad= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many oranges do you need: ");
orangesTheyNeed = Integer.parseInt(orangesHad);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must order " + applesToOrder + "         apples and " + orangesToOrder + " oranges!");
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think that you can perform the subtraction before `applesTheyNeed` and `applesTheyHave` have their values from the input?

Comment: Didn't ask that question, i'll keep that in mind next time. tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very simple you are  not calculating `applesToOrder` and `orangesToOrder` again after user input so they are taking there previous values of `0`, just put these lines just above your last `JOptionPane` statement and see the magic.

```
 applesToOrder = applesTheyNeed - applesTheyHave;
 orangesToOrder = orangesTheyNeed - orangesTheyHave;
```

Comment: Great. Overlooked that detail when putting everything together. I'll remember that next time. tks

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the mat operation BEFORE the user gives the input values,
move this after the JOptionPane section....

```
applesToOrder = applesTheyNeed - applesTheyHave;
orangesToOrder = orangesTheyNeed - orangesTheyHave;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this

```
applesToOrder = applesTheyNeed - applesTheyHave;
orangesToOrder = orangesTheyNeed - orangesTheyHave;
```

the values of `applesTheyNeed`, and all other variables is `0`, therefore the `applesToOrder` is read like this

> applesToOrder = applesTheyNeed - applesTheyHave
>
> applesToOrder = 0 - 0
>
> applesToOrder = 0

Changing the value `applesTheyNeed`  and others afterwards , **won't affect the value of** `applesToOrder`

*To fix this*, simply **put the statements after taking the input**